# List files which is greater than X value and less than Y

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am having some files on unix server, which having a name like abc_**250**-00.txt.
Now I want to list the files which are greater than X value but less than Y.

for example:-
below are the list of files

```
abc_**100**-00.txt
xyz_**101**-000.txt
abc_**200**-00.txt
xyz_**201**-000.txt
abc_**250**-00.txt
xyz_**290**-000.txt
abc_**300**-00.txt
xyz_**350**-000.txt
```

I need the result of the list of files which are greater than XXX_**201**-xx.txt but less than XXX_**300**-xx.txt.

abc_**250**-00.txt

xyz_**290**-000.txt

I have tried with ls and combine with awk but I am not getting the proper result.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are the files `abc_250-00.txt` or `abc_**250**-00.txt`? You have both in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ ls *.txt | awk -F[-_] '201<$2 && $2<300'

abc_250-00.txt
xyz_290-000.txt
```

if there are other files you don't want to be part of the search, you may want to restrict `ls` with `ls *_[0-9][0-9][0-9]-00*.txt`

Answer (score 0):

No subshell required.

```
echo "abc_100-00.txt
xyz_101-000.txt
abc_200-00.txt
xyz_201-000.txt
abc_250-00.txt
xyz_290-000.txt
abc_300-00.txt
xyz_350-000.txt" |
while read -f f
do n=${f#???_}
   n=${n%-*} 
   if (( n < 300 )) && (( n > 201 )) 
   then echo $f
   fi
done
```

Still, an `awk` would likely be faster. :)

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
$ ls -1
abc_**100**-00.txt
abc_**200**-00.txt
abc_**250**-00.txt
abc_**300**-00.txt
xyz_**101**-000.txt
xyz_**201**-000.txt
xyz_**290**-000.txt
xyz_**350**-000.txt
```

You can use Perl:

```
$ ls -1 | perl -lnE 'say if (m/(?<=\*)(\d{3})(?=\*)/ && 201<$1 && $1<300)'
abc_**250**-00.txt
xyz_**290**-000.txt
```